# std::unique_ptr saving reference in a Factory class?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to utilize a ConnectionPoolFactory (let's call it Factory A) this factory creates a `std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool>` .. i understand this unique pointer cannot be copied (otherwise it won't stay unique)..

but how can I pass this reference to another factory (let's call it Factory B) for use?

The error that occurs on compilation

```
thrift_server.cpp: In constructor ‘thriftserverHandlerFactory::thriftserverHandlerFactory(const char*, int, const std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool>&)’:
thrift_server.cpp:237:27: error: cannot convert ‘const std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool>’ to ‘cpool::ConnectionPool*’ in assignment
  237 |       this->tma_conn_pool=conn_pool;
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~
      |                           |
      |                           const std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool>
```

Factory B - this is an Apache Thrift Server Handler factory... as clients connect to this thrift server.. they should share the same connection pool and if all connections are busy.. we will either pause or timeout new connections

```
class thriftserverHandlerFactory : public thriftserverIfFactory {
  public:
    ibrokersHandlerFactory(const char* target_thriftserver_host, int target_thriftserver_port, const std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool> & conn_pool) {
      this->handler_num=0;
      this->tma_conn_pool=conn_pool;
    }

...

  private:
      unsigned int handler_num;
      cpool::ConnectionPool* tma_conn_pool;
};
```

Factory A

```
template <>
class cpool::ConnectionPoolFactory<TMAConnection> {

public:
    static std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool> create( const std::uint16_t num_connections ) {
        std::vector< std::unique_ptr<cpool::Connection> > connections;
        for ( std::uint16_t k = 0; k < num_connections; ++k ) {
            // cannot use std::make_unique, because constructor is hidden
            connections.emplace_back( std::unique_ptr<TMAConnection>( new TMAConnection{} ) );
        }
        return std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool>( new cpool::ConnectionPool{std::move( connections )} );
    }
};
```

Comment: At the risk of promoting an incredibly dangerous alternative, make `tma_conn_pool` a member *reference*, e.g. `const std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool>& tma_conn_pool;` in the class def, and initialize it in the member/base initialization list where it not only belongs, but is no longer optional; as a reference, it *must* be initialized there. Note: dangerous because you're setting up a very brittle potential lifetime issue (twice, in fact). Frankly, I think a shared pointer may be a better alternative, but to each their own.

Comment: Which of the factories can you rewrite as they are your code? How is the connection pool in Factory B used? Can you just change the type of tma_conn_pool? Is the connection pool created with Factory A just used in B (then it would not need to be shared, just be created with A and used in B? (BTW the type of Factory B is called differently than the constructor). If you cannot copy the pool / unique_ptr, you could move it instead! Then the destruction would be handled correctly.

Comment: Just like with any resource that can't be copied, you can still pass by reference. I'm not sure if that properly represents the semantics of your case though.

Comment: "they should share the same connection pool" suggests `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Instead `this->tma_conn_pool=conn_pool;` write `this->tma_conn_pool=conn_pool.get();`, this will compile. But beware that if unique_ptr is destructed then this copied raw pointer will be invalid and crash program. So code should stop using `this->tma_conn_pool` field before unique_ptr is destructed.

Comment: Only use `shared_ptr`, if ownership cannot be solved in another way. Either move ownership into Factory B or keep it in owner of Factory B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smart pointer `sharing` issue is something you are already aware of, so focusing on the *how to pass and assign a reference* question.

**What's wrong**

Reference variables (const declared ones aswell) can be assigned only once during initialization. This is what the compiler would complain about if the types would match.

**How to fix**

Standard variables can be instantiated and assigned at once like this

```
int a = 0;
int& b = a;
```

For classes/structs it's working slightly different. Instead of assignment in the constructor body, do this in the initializer list after `:`

```
class a {
int& ref;
a (int& b)
: ref{b} {}
};
```

In your example this would look like this:

```
class thriftserverHandlerFactory : public thriftserverIfFactory {
  public:
    ibrokersHandlerFactory(const char* target_thriftserver_host, int target_thriftserver_port, const cpool::ConnectionPool& conn_pool) 
    : handler_num{0}, 
    tma_conn_pool {conn_pool}
    {}
  private:
      unsigned int handler_num;
      const cpool::ConnectionPool& tma_conn_pool;
};
```

I was not sure about the exact type you want to have, since constructor and member did not match (guess because of experimenting), so used `cpool::ConnectionPool&`in my example.
You might want to modify `tma_conn_pool` to a type that matches (e.g. `cpool::ConnectionPool&`, or a smart pointer of choice).

This is anyway a good practice to initialize all members like this, because that way you avoid creating members with default values and assign in body.

Comment: when I print my ConnectionPool by reference out using `std::cout` I am seeing slightly different pointer addresses.. should I be concerned ?  I successfully compile but want to trace that the address made in Main.cpp properly gets passed down

Comment: this helped confirm btw, that I can use pass by reference in the factory constructor, thank you Chris

Comment: Happy to help @Erik! The adresses of both `tma_conn_pool` should be the same when stored as reference, since a reference is just an alias.

Comment: I successfully got the address pushed down into FactoryB's results!  phew... !  I just had to fumble a bit with pointers and references to pointers etc etc etc...